# How to add label to div in typescript file (React)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to typescript an having warnings saying that:
`Property 'label' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>` in a tsx file.

```
<div label="apple">
    Apple!
</div>
<div label="orange">
    Orange!
</div>
```

The code is compiled successfully, but that warning is annoying me.

How can I solve this warning?

Answer (score 2):

The `label` attribute isn't a valid attribute on a `div` tag. Do you mean to use `aria-label` instead?